# Android System services cant be instantiated directly when creating handlers

Tags: android

Why cant we instantiate a system service directly such as the location manager when creating an object. Instead we do this

getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: that cant be a reason enough for the downvote,,my question is why cant we directly create an instance of a system service the way we do with other classes when we create objects of them,, instead we call the getSystemService method then we parse the location service...hope u get it now,,,and the downvote look pretty ugly!

Comment: Please post an example of code which doesn't work and the error you get.

Comment: That method is called from Context class, each time that you call it, a instance from the Service is returned (Singleton pattern), and I have not voted neither negative nor positive. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: mins you cant code what you dont understand so i wanted to know why it is always done that way. @juanhl +1 for mentioning the singleton pattern in your answer.

Comment: But now do you?Or is any part still unclear?

Comment: @Droidekas hey thanks u made the whole thing clear by mentioning the  singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you require a system service which exists as a singular service in that system.This is based on the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
Having multiple objects of the same Service would conflict with the design of Android where LocationManager is a single service for that type of Context.

from the [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29)

> Note: System services obtained via this API may be closely associated with the Context in which they are obtained from. In general, do not share the service objects between various different contexts (Activities, Applications, Services, Providers, etc.)

Imagine if each different type of context had to maintain different types of services

Another reason would also be that many of these services require permissions in the manifest.A centralised(System-based) approach to obtain the services can also ensure the right permissions possessed by the application.